# What does the `return` command really do when sourcing a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, return

Consider this MRE Bash Script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# mre.sh

(return 0) && echo SUCCESS || echo FAILURE
echo DONE
```

According to the man pages:

> The return utility shall cause the shell to stop executing the current function or dot script.

The documentation doesn't say anything about subshells, so I interpret it to mean that it doesn't matter.

However, when I test this:

```bash
$ . mre.sh
SUCCESS
DONE
```

According to the man pages, the `return 0` should stop executing commands in the script. Which means that nothing should be printed to my terminal.

⚠️ The `return` utility clearly does NOT stop executing the dot script.

To me, it looks like the `return` utility, used in the scope of a dot script, will return to the calling shell. In this case, we're in a subshell, so we return to the shell where `mre.sh` was sourced... but we're still inside the script, and executing the remaining commands!

However, I can not find any documentation, user manual, reference manual,... that specifies the behavior that I'm observing.

I am looking for a pointer to a reference that explains the behavior correctly.

Comment: `return` is for **functions**

Comment: @gilles Quenot: It is for both functions, and scripts that are sourced. If you're not putting the `return` in a subshell, then the `return` will effectively leave the script indeed.

Comment: See: `help return`

Comment: Subshells cannot affect the execution of the parent shell (except via their exit status). That means that `return`, `exit`, `break`, `continue`, etc don't work as you might expect when they occur in a subshell.

Comment: I know that a subshell can not affect the ENVIRONMENT of a parent SHELL. But my question is indeed asking where I can find a reference on the impact of a subshell on the execution of a SCRIPT...

Comment: `return` *is* causing the subshell to terminate, but you are missing the fact that the subshell is that defined by `()`.  Consider `(echo in subshell; return 0; echo you will not see this) && echo SUCCESS || echo FAILURE`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: That is my question: the references do not say anything about SUBSHELLS being terminated by `return`. The `return` terminates FUNCTIONS and SOURCED SCRIPTS. So why is my sourced script not terminated, if I put the `return` in a subshell?

Comment: @WilliamPursell When I write the command `(echo in subshell; return 0; echo you will not see this) && echo SUCCESS || echo FAILURE` directly in the terminal (running bash 5.2), the text `you will not see this` is printed! (along with other lines). When I source the exact command, then that text isn't printed. These two behaviours aren't consistent.

Comment: @Flandraco I think the real question should have been something like that: Why does the command `(return 0) && echo SUCCESS || echo FAILURE` behave differently when it is run directly from command-line, and when it is sourced.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Do you get error `-bash: return: can only 'return' from a function or sourced script` when you write the command `(echo in subshell; return 0; echo you will not see this) && echo SUCCESS || echo FAILURE` directly in the terminal ?

Comment: I think this is ambiguous documentation.  The word "script" in the expression "current function or dot script" is ill-defined and should be more precise, perhaps "current function or sourced environment" or "subshell".   The subshell is the "current script".

Comment: @Philippe Yes, I do.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin: the answer to that question (different behavior for sourcing versus executing a script) *is* actually documented: since `return` only works to return from a function or a SOURCED script (dot script), you will get an error message in an executed script.  And that is not my original question. The original question is to why the return in a subshell in a sourced script, does not terminate said script (as documented).

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I agree, I think I will log an issue with the documentation of this `utility` (Bash repo).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing this behavior is because you are creating a sub-process with:

```
(return 0)
```

the return exits the sub process and continues executing from where it started.

If you had done the following:

```
{
return 0
}
```

It would have returned from sourcing the script.

Comment: The question is: why does the return NOT terminate the sourcing of a dot script (as documented), when you put it in a subshell.

Terminating a dot script is the documented behavior (it doesn't put any restrictions on it being in a subshell or not).

Comment: U could play with: `testRet(){ (return $1) && echo Success || echo Fail;return $1;echo Done.;}` , run alternatively `testRet 0;echo $?` and `testRet 1;echo $?` then never seeing `Done.` printed.

Comment: @Flandraco *it doesn't put any restrictions on it being in a subshell or not*... If a ***function*** or ***sourced script*** run a ***subshell***, and ***this*** subshell exit, there are ***no reason*** the ***parent*** *function* or *sourced script* will die!

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub: **The return utility shall cause the shell to stop executing the ... dot script**.

This reads to me as **The return utility shall skip any other lines in the dot script, and continue after the source command of said script**.  But the observation is that the `return` will just hand over control to the calling shell, even if that calling shell is still part of the dot script.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing it wrong, because it's in a subshell not in the sourced script.

```
#! /bin/bash

. mre.sh
echo 'PARENT' $?
```

and

```
# mre.sh

echo 'MRE.SH'
return 5
echo DONE
```

then, executing

```
./parent
```

prints

```
MRE.SH
PARENT 5
```

as expected.

Comment: My test is the question: why does the `return` not terminate the script, IF it is called in a subshell of a sourced script.

If I call the `return` command from a subshell in a function, then I return immediately from that function.

Similarly, and according to the references, if I call the `return`  command from a subshell in a sourced script (and NOT in a function), then I expect to return immediately from that script.

Comment: @Flandraco "If I call the return command from a subshell in a function, then I return immediately from that function."  That is not the behavior I see.  In which version of which shell do you see that behavior?

Answer (score -1):

> The documentation doesn't say anything about subshells

It does not NEED to say anything about `return` in subshells, because it goes without saying that anything happening inside subshells does not affect current execution environment.

See [`Changes made to the subshell environment cannot affect the shell’s execution environment`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#:%7E:text=Changes%20made%20to%20the%20subshell%20environment%20cannot%20affect%20the%20shell%E2%80%99s%20execution%20environment)

Comment: The statement is correct. You can not change any shell variables (the "environment") from a subshell. But that doesn't have anything to do with the behavior of the `return` command in a subshell.

Comment: The `environment` is not restricted to shell variables.

Comment: My apologies for the poor description (trying to keep comments short). There are options, aliases, functions, jobs,... indeed. And a subshell can not affect any of those.

But again, the `return` command doesn't affect any of those! It just returns from a function, or it returns from the sourced script, to the point where the script was sourced (without affecting the environment). Or that is what the current documentation implies.